# only change layout color while orientation change android

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-orientation

I have create dialog box which will be displayed first when i start application (which is coded in onCreate method ) and then question and answer will be displayed on textview

so to solve problem of orientation (so dialog box again not displayed when orientation change) i have used Manifest with:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

I have `res/layout-land`, `res/layout-port`

but to change only COLOR of background

I have used `onConfigurationChanged` in my Activity (it get's called on rotation).

so now when orientation change the dialog box will not appear again and background is redrawn but the question and answer which is initialized on `onCreate()` will not display

so how to maintain

Answer (score 1):

Using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` means that your activity handles a configuration change itself, and the system will not change the layout.. take a lokk at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

To reset the text view, **in case of not using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`**:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final MyDataObject data = collectMyLoadedData();
     //here get the text from the text view, and any other info
    return data;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyDataObject data = (MyDataObject) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data != null) {
       //get the text and set it in the text view
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya your are right but i want to display text which remain same as before orientation change

Answer (score 0):

When you change the orientation of the devide, android continue the execution without calling onCreate again, but if you put the code in onResume, this code will executed again.

Comment: but by putting code on onResume will asking me question again new!!! which should be remain same as before orientation change....

Answer (score 0):

In OnCreate add for your main layout as

```
 LinearLayout lv=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
  lv.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);  // for default potrait or landscape view and after that add this in that activity

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

  if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
    // portrait
     lv.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
  } else if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
    // landscape
    lv.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
  }
}
```

and also add this in menifest in your activity defined

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the data and `onRestoreInstanceState` for retriving the data?
If you have done this then you can display the same dialog box in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Well I have a question for you. How did you kept the background color unchanged when changing the orientations? And what to do if the color is unknown or a random color?